Google Cloud Function Test Environment doesn't detect code changes
I am trying to test changes to Cloud Function code without having to deploy in between each change. I have a deployed, working function with the below specs using the standard template code:
Version: 2nd Gen
Trigger type: Cloud Storage: object.v1.finalized
Runtime service account: Compute Engine default service account
Runtime: Python 3.12

import functions_framework

# Triggered by a change in a storage bucket
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_gcs(cloud_event):
    data = cloud_event.data

    event_id = cloud_event["id"]
    event_type = cloud_event["type"]

    bucket = data["bucket"]
    name = data["name"]
    metageneration = data["metageneration"]
    timeCreated = data["timeCreated"]
    updated = data["updated"]

    print(f"Event ID: {event_id}")
    print(f"Event type: {event_type}")
    print(f"Bucket: {bucket}")
    print(f"File: {name}")
    print(f"Metageneration: {metageneration}")
    print(f"Created: {timeCreated}")
    print(f"Updated: {updated}")

When I upload a file to the cloud bucket, it is properly triggered
When I edit my code in-browser and click "Test Function" a test environment and triggering event is spun up (and cloud shell is authorized).

I then edit the code in the function to delete 6 of the 7 print statements. The new function reads:
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def hello_gcs(cloud_event):
    data = cloud_event.data

    event_id = cloud_event["id"]
    event_type = cloud_event["type"]

    bucket = data["bucket"]
    name = data["name"]
    metageneration = data["metageneration"]
    timeCreated = data["timeCreated"]
    updated = data["updated"]

    print(f"Event ID: {event_id}")

When I select "run test", the shell still prints all 7 lines:
Event type: google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized
Bucket: some-bucket
File: folder/Test.cs
Metageneration: 1
Created: 2020-04-23T07:38:57.230Z
Updated: 2020-04-23T07:38:57.230Z

Meaning, it doesn't recognize the code change made to the function.
I have tried this with other functions and other code changes and the general issue is that no function changes are detected when using the "Test Function" functionality. What am I doing wrong here as this use to work fine a few weeks ago.


On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Hi @DougStevenson I appreciate the recommendation. The relevant text from the images is pasted in the question. The images are just to show the test environment that I am referencing from the GCP Console. Hope that is clear when reading the question!

The last two images are exceptionally difficult to read.  Why don't you paste that into the question?  If you want to maximize your changes of getting your question answered, it's a good idea to make your question as easy to read as possible. It will also maximize the chances of helping someone else who pasts the same text into a search query.

All of the code from the screenshots is indeed in the question in formatted text as well. The screenshots just provide additional context if someone is attempting to recreate the issue in their browser, they can see what the output looks like visually in addition to just the text.
